# Is the value of a Linux file descriptor always smaller than the open file limits?

Tags: linux

Is the "value" of a Linux file descriptor always smaller the open file limits ?

Theoretically, the system shall re-use the identity values of closed file descriptors. And I should get file descriptor values ranged from 0,1,2 up to 1023 by default, after opened 1021 files in one process. If I want to open another file, I have to release some file descriptors with `close`, and system shall re-use these released identities when I call `open` again. So the maximum integer value of a file descriptor should be 1023 in this case. Is that correct ?

I know that I can change the open file limits with `ulimit -n`, `setrlimit`, and `/proc/sys/fs/file-max`. I just want to know whether I can store an opened socket file descriptor with a `char` variable, if I had reduced the open file limits to 128 with `setrlimit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the values are limited to the range from 0 to one less than the current limit as returned by getrlimit().

[From the getrlimit() man page:](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html)

> ```
>    RLIMIT_NOFILE
>           Specifies a value one greater than the maximum file descriptor number
>           that can be opened by this process.  Attempts (open(2), pipe(2),
>           dup(2), etc.)  to exceed this limit yield the error EMFILE.
>           (Historically, this limit was named RLIMIT_OFILE on BSD.)
> ```

[From the Open Group Base Specification:](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/getrlimit.html)

> RLIMIT_NOFILE 
>       This is a number one greater than the maximum value that the system may assign to a newly-created descriptor. If this limit is
>   exceeded, functions that allocate a file descriptor shall fail with
>   errno set to [EMFILE]. This limit constrains the number of file
>   descriptors that a process may allocate.

Comment: Thanks. The man page of getrlimit() on my computer only says "RLIMIT_NOFILE: The maximum number of open files for this process."