# Are parallel calls to `fstat`, `lstat` or `stat` limited by the open file limit on linux?

Tags: linux, libc

Pretty much as in the title:

Are parallel calls to `fstat`, `lstat` or `stat` limited by the open file limit on linux?

The question probably boils down to, whether those calls (`fstat`, `lstat`, `stat`) will use a file descriptor internally in any way, if I interpret the answer to the question [Is the value of a Linux file descriptor always smaller than the open file limits?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12585752) correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of these open any file, so they’re not directly affected.  That said, `fstat` *accepts* a file descriptor, so you must have one open (but the number of calls to `fstat` is irrelevant).